Facing issue while hiding the scrolled table content
I am working on a use case where we want elements on a screen to be fixed like header, sidebar, searchbox. We also have a table container under the searcbox element. The table container should always take the dynamic height. problem is when I started scrolling the page, the table content started scrolling  but some of the content is visible, attached the screenshot for reference.



#header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #880016; 
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: fixed;
}
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#table-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#searchbox {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
#table-content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 50%;
}
<div id="header">
    header header header header header header
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>SideBar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="table-container">
    <div id="searchbox">Searchbox</div>
    <div id="table-content">
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p><p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I tried it with a blind.


#header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #880016; 
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}
#blind{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 110px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#table-container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#searchbox {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 5;
}
#table-content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}
<div id="header">
    header header header header header header
</div>
<div id="blind">
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <p>SideBar</p>
  </div>
  <div id="table-container">
    <div id="searchbox">Searchbox</div>
    <div id="table-content">
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p><p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
      <p>In common usage, data is a collection of discrete or continuous values that convey information, describing the quantity, quality, fact, statistics, other basic units of meaning, or simply sequences of symbols that may be further interpreted formally. A datum is an individual value in a collection of data</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



The rest is z-index.
